# Detecting which workspace you're in from the command line

Tags: linux, bash, workspace

I'm trying to write myself a little function to help me keep track of what I'm doing, the idea being that in each workspace I have a different task underway, and a different "todo.txt" file for each workspace. I can certainly specify, when I call the command, which workspace I'm in, but I'd really like to automatically detect which and alter the appropriate file.

Is there any way to determine which workspace I'm in from the command line, so I can use it in a bash function?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, workspaces are managed by the window manager. Which window manager are you using?

Comment: I'm on a RHEL5 box; so Gnome?

Answer (score 3):

xprop -root -notype _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP

Answer (score 1):

If you're using metacity and python you can do something like this:

```
python -c "import wnck; s=wnck.screen_get_default(); s.force_update(); w=s.get_active_workspace();  w_num=w.get_number(); print(w_num);" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Nope. Pure Bash. Not sure I am allowed to get Python working on this machine, as it's a work machine and they're a bit restrictive as to what I can install.