# How can I tell which Xfce workspace is currently visible from a bash command on terminal in that workspace?

Tags: bash, xfce

I want to run a slightly different bash command depending on which Xfce workspace I am running on.  How can I get the Xfce workspace name (or some unique number) for the current workspace on the bash commandline.  Well actually from an alias.

Answer (score 1):

`xprop -root -notype _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

This works from a bash terminal in Xfce on CentOS 7.

I found the answer here, but the accepted answer there didn't work for me.

[Detecting which workspace you're in from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445518/detecting-which-workspace-youre-in-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

From [askubuntu Is there a way to detect which workspace you are currently in from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17484/is-there-a-way-to-detect-which-workspace-you-are-currently-in-from-the-command-l) I have glued the following script:

```
workspace=$(xdotool get_desktop)
case "$workspace" in
0) one_command; ;;
1) another_command; ;;
esac
```

Comment: Sounds good.  I'm on CentOS 7 and I don't have access to xdotool unfortunately though.

Comment: Try finding it with `wmctrl` or maybe somewhere it will be listed in `xfce4-query`

Comment: I don't have wmctrl at my disposal either.  Doh!